# Set duration for Toast messages in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

Is there a way to set the duration for custom Toast messages in LWC? I know, in Aura we do it using Duration attribute, but looks like in case of LWC there is no 'Duration' attribute defined. Also, looks like Custom Toast messages are still in BETA version in LWC so I can't deploy it to PROD right? Any idea when would it be GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option for a duration, the only options are to provide a close button, wait three seconds, or do both. "Beta" components are those that are "production quality, but with known limitations." You can use beta components in production, but you need to be aware of limitations (in this case, there's no duration you can set!).

Comment: Got it.. Thanks for your help..!!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use    mode : 'sticky',   parameter. This made toast message to stay there until user clicks the close (X) and clears it. This worked for me as some of my messages are very long that can't be ready within 3 seconds.  [toast parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_toast)